# Linking error with iOS app with cross-referencing multiple static libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, static-linking

I'm splitting up an Xcode iPhone project into multiple smaller projects for code reuse.
The structure looks like this:

```
+------------+
|    App     |
+------------+
      |
      +------------------+
      |                  |
+--------------+ +--------------+
| Static Lib A | | Static Lib B |
+--------------+ +--------------+
        |                |
        +----------------+
                |
         +--------------+  +----------------+
         | Static Lib Z |--| Static Lib KAL |
         +--------------+  +----------------+
```

Everything compiles correctly, but as soon as the app is linked, the linker cannot find 2 symbols of the KAL (the open source calendar lib) library.
Each library has a cross-reference and all the archives are added to the "Link binary with libraries" build phase.

The errors are:

Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KalViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-KalViewController in libA.a(AViewController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KalDate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-KalDate in libA.a(AViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm using a class from LibZ in LibA's AViewController which in his turn is using a class in LibKAL.

PS: the separation of A and B is simply because not every build of App needs the functionality provided by the two.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so like many people, having spent several evenings trying to figure this out I managed to get it to work almost right after placing this.
The problem was that when I had added the references to the library projects, Xcode aded the projects itself as dependencies, instead of the archive files. Which was the cause of the linker (obviously) not finding the symbols.